# Dropdown Menu in Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, drop-down-menu, navigation

I want to implement a dropdown menu in a website build using ZF 1.X

in my application/layouts/layout.phtml i have the call

```
$this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(   
    $this->navigation()->findByLabel('My Account'),
    array('maxDepth' => 0)
);
```

In myapp/Controller/Plugin/Navigation.php i see the menu labeled "My Account":

```
$account_container = new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
            array(
                  'route' => 'account_index',
                  'label' => 'My Account',
                  'pages' => array(
                        new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
                            array(
                            'route' => 'productions_list',
                            'label' => 'My Productions',
                            )
                        ),
                        new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
                            array(
                                'route' => 'productions_create',
                                'label' => 'Create a Production',
                            )
                        ),
                        new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
                            array(
                                'route' => 'account_inbox',
                                'label' => sprintf('My Inbox (%s)', $ident->getAllUnreadMessagesCount()),
                                'id' => 'inbox-count'
                            )
                        ),
                        new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
                            array(
                                 'route' => 'search_search_productions',
                                 'label' => 'Search Productions'
                            )
                        ),
                        new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
                            array(
                                 'route' => 'search_search_users',
                                 'label' => 'Search Users'
                            )
                        ),
                  )
            )
        );
```

and this generates

```
<ul class="navigation"> 
    <li class="active"><a href="/news">Blog</a></li>
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

I need to add nested level using UL like this:

```
<ul class="navigation"> 
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/news">Blog</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/somethingelse">link</a></li>
            ...
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

What's the way to do this? i need this to generate a Dropdown menu in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
'maxDepth' => 1 is not enough,

the need it to implement new pages in the child array:

```
$account_container = new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
        array(
              'route' => 'account_index',
              'label' => 'My Account',
              'pages' => array(
                    new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
                        array(
                        'route' => 'productions_list',
                        'label' => 'My Productions',
                        'pages' => array(
                            new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
                            array(
                                'route' => 'mychildurl',
                                'label' => 'My Child Label',
                            )
                        ),
                        )
                    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you simply need to set :

`'maxDepth' => 1`

Instead of 0.